# Common base transistor biasing

Tags: bjt, bias

I have a basic question regarding bipolar junction transistors.As far as i know, the correct biasing of the transistor is achieved using a process known commonly as base bias.Correct me if i am wrong. Base bias networks can be used for Common-base (CB), common-collector (CC) or common-emitter (CE) transistor configurations.My question is, how does biasing of a common base configuration is done? or in other words, how to base bias a common base configuration transistor?

Comment: A couple of series resistors from power to ground with midpoint to the base. Decoupler cap on base to ground too.

Comment: @Andyaka why do we need decoupling capacitor?

Comment: Realize a common-emitter stage (with Re-feedback). If you feed the signal into the emitter instead of the base node. Then, you have a common-base amplifier (DC operatinmg point unchangend) - if you ground the base for ac signals (capacitor).

Comment: @LvW thank you for your feedback. Now i get how biasing is done.

Answer (score 1):

For the transistor to work in conduction, its \$V_{BE} \ge 0.6V\$.  For a common base circuit, you can achieve this for example by grounding the base and biasing the emitter input negatively.

The following circuit illustrates the principle:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fUMijW.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Or if you do not have a negative rail, you can bias the base with a resistor divider, as Andy suggested.

Comment: Please forgive the awkward voltage rails layout.  Is there a better way to do this with circuitlab, and still have a simulating circuit?

Comment: Just single-click the component, then Right-Click on the component to bring up the properties dialog box.  Then select "Flip Vertically".

Comment: @corecode and dwayne : thanks guys, appreciate the explanation.

Answer (score 0):

you have same circuit as voltage divider CE amplifier with degeneration resistor; no bypass cap on it; simply connect a large capacitor like 10 micro to the base where its connected to divider resistors and the other side to ground; this will form an AC ground point while blocking DC bias from getting drained to ground